# react-native-sensitive-info Cannot read property setItem of undefined

Tags: javascript, android, ios, react-native, security

**Issue**

react-native-sensitive-info isn't working on iOS, I keep getting the error "setItem is undefined" because it seems SInfo is not loading properly.

I can launch perfectly on Android though.

**What I've tried**

I've tried multiple different values and placing it in many different points in my code.  Currently I'm using the first example outlined on their Github and it's still not working.

**Code**

```
import React from 'react';
import { 
  StyleSheet, 
  AsyncStorage 
} from 'react-native';

import firebase from 'react-native-firebase';
import SInfo from 'react-native-sensitive-info';
import SplashScreen from 'react-native-splash-screen';
import AppContainer from './Components/BottomTabNav';


export default class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super();
    this.state = {
       userData: {}
    };
      SInfo.setItem('key1', 'value1', {
          sharedPreferencesName: 'mySharedPrefs',
          keychainService: 'myKeychain'
        }).then((value) =>
          console.log(value) //value 1
        )
  }
```

If anyone has any suggestions that would be great!  Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: The library is most likely just not set up properly on the Android side of things. Make sure that you're importing it correctly in your MainApplication

Comment: It's actually working perfectly for Android but I get that error on iOS.  Any suggestions @Kai ?

Comment: Definitely double check that it's installed properly, all the same. Maybe delete and reinstall your pods too

Comment: I checked my pod file and it’s included in there.  I also tried installing it in a new project and I’m still running into the same issue.  Do you think I should still delete and reinstall my pods?  I haven’t done that before so I’m a little worried about breaking my project

Comment: Don't worry about it, it's no bigger an issue than deleting node_modules. Make sure that the output from `pod install` shows that it was installed correctly, and check that the linker stuff in xcode is set up properly per the instructions in the readme

Answer (score 0):

It's seems to a be quirk of the library on iOS where protected data isn't always available on app start...

See issue (unresolved):
https://github.com/mCodex/react-native-sensitive-info/issues/326

See comment in library code:
https://github.com/mCodex/react-native-sensitive-info/blob/master/ios/RNSensitiveInfo/RNSensitiveInfo.m#L263

The less than ideal workaround (for now) seems to be to wrap the RNSInfo access in a try catch and keep re-trying until there is no error.

You may need some sort of throttling here though with a limit on the number of retries. You won't want to keep retrying infinitely if there is some other kind of error being thrown.